# Update and select using single query in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to  update the  columns and select the values using single query in MySQL

For example

```
update table set address='bangalore',updated_count =updated_count+1 where id=1 
select * from table where id=1
```

Comment: What happens when you execute that exact code?  What isn't working?  What's the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: That is two query update and select ,but i want to execute both action in single query

Comment: you could not do `update` and `select` in a same query, why would you want to do that?

Comment: @MangalaSamy: "Updating" and "selecting" are two different operations.  If you just want to arbitrarily combine them for no logical reason then I suppose the acceptable answer is "you can't".

Comment: Create a procedure?

Comment: Yes,i have idea to create store procedure, before that i just check possible to execute in one query

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible. As @D-Shih mentioned, you cannot do both update and select in the same query. The SQL `update` convention doesn't allow for return data and the `select` statement can't write to a table.

Each has its own purpose and can't be written in one statement. They must be executed separately.